# How to Get image when dynamic link comes from a website

Tags: python, html, download

I want to get the full resolution image displayed from this website : 
http://oiswww.eumetsat.org/IPPS/html/MSG/PRODUCTS/MPE/FULLRESOLUTION/index.htm

The image has a dynamic link every time when it is updated, which cause problem if we want to download it every time.

Do you have some tricks with python to systematically download the full resolution image.

Thanks all.

Comment: First download the HTML, then find image URL in HTML and download that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), [lxml](http://lxml.de/) or a Python [RegExp](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to parse the HTML and get the correct link, there should be an xpath to it.

Comment: I want to get the latest image (array_nom_imagen[0]=). how can i do that with Python

Answer (score 0):

From the source code of the html:

```
array_nom_imagen[0]="wwCzemwbmWlTk"
array_nom_imagen[1]="CtXqGo6wG8hVz"
array_nom_imagen[2]="8UFuyfrkbcd0b"
...
...
array_nom_imagen[138]="fFoSqmGjl6zhJ"
array_nom_imagen[139]="S5QefAKEdpWQf"
array_nom_imagen[140]="vCcabHqeoVgdv"
```

and

```
function loadimages(i_image) {
  array_imagen[i_image] = new Image()
  array_imagen[i_image].src = "IMAGESDisplay/"+array_nom_imagen[i_image]
  imageurl[i_image]="IMAGESDisplay/"+array_nom_imagen[i_image]
  loaded_images[i_image]="TRUE"
}
```

So only 141 pictures are available.

Comment: Exactely and always i want to get the latest image (array_nom_imagen[0]=). how can i do that with python